# Is there a better way to write lots of repeated instances of "if(string.IsNullOrEmpty())"

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

Sorry if this is something that has been answered before, I wasn't really sure what to search for. I have some code which has lots of null/empty checks before executing single lines of code. It's quite ugly and I feel like there's probably a better way to do this.

Example:

```
private XElement getWhereXMLNode()
{
    XElement where = new XElement("where");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(County))
    {
        where.Add(new XElement("county", County));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(District))
    {
        where.Add(new XElement("district", District));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Parish))
    {
        where.Add(new XElement("parishLAStyle", Parish));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParliamentaryConstituency))
    {
        where.Add(new XElement("parCon", ParliamentaryConstituency));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GovernmentRegion))
    {
         where.Add(new XElement("govReg", GovernmentRegion));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainQuery))
    {
        where.Add(new XElement("freetext_where", MainQuery));
    }

    return where;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a different way to do working code. Please ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: Oh sorry, are refactoring questions not allowed here?

Comment: yea. we fix broken code.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly [valid question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are many good quality questions on Stack Overflow asking about code optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can use the fact that LINQ to XML ignores null values on construction. Create a small local method that takes an element name and the value, and returns either an element or null:

```
private XElement CreateWhereElement()
{
    return new XElement("where",
        CreateChild("county", County),
        CreateChild("district", District),
        CreateChild("parishLAStyle", Parish),
        CreateChild("parCon", ParliamentaryConstituency),
        CreateChild("govReg", GovernmentRegion),
        CreateChild("freetext_where", MainQuery));

    XElement CreateChild(string name, string value) =>
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : new XElement(name, value);
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but does it not ignore the `null` value on addition as well? If that's the [case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354061(v=vs.110).aspx), he can probably use .Add() without any checks.

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer: Yes it does, but I don't think that helps - you'd still need to conditionally create the child elements; otherwise you'd just end up with empty child elements.